# calling javascript function from body of html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascrip[t function that is saved in a file (test.js). I want to call the function from within the body of the html file

something like

```
<script>
    load drawLogo("text" val1, val2, val3);
</script>
```

(since this function will be called on different pages with different values)

Right now I am having to put that call at the bottom of the main function drawLogo() which means I can't customize it.

Comment: ANd what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="text.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if it is in same function then make it like:-
 onclick="func()" or onmmousehover="func()"
 define function func() in the same file within script tag

Answer (score 0):

Just put the function name and the parameters that receive this, dont forget first call the js file:

test.js:

```
function drawLogo(paramText,value1,value2,value3){
    //Do something
}
```

html:

```
<head>
   <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!--you can put this in the head or in the body-->
   <script>
   drawLogo("some","value","for","example");
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <!--you can put this in the head or in the body-->
   <script>
   drawLogo("some","value","for","example");
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem I was having was that I had to place the script call after the canvas declaration. Doh. `       <canvas id="logo" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         drawLogo();` works fine, but if I put the canvas line second, it fails.